# Not getting email from facebook after logging success, it is giving name only

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();  
fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data" + object.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            etEmail.setText(object.optString("email"));
                            etName.setText(object.optString("name"));


                        }
                    }).executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });


    buttonFbSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fbLoginButton.performClick();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have integrated facebook sdk properly but not getting email on success

Comment: you set the email permission (and hopefully get asked for it in the login popup), but there is no api call asking for the email. make sure you know what "declarative fields" means, this would be the api call to get the user email: /me?fields=email

Comment: please help how i can do this?

Comment: i am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `email` permission (and hopefully get asked for it in the login popup), but there is no API call asking for the email. Make sure you know what "declarative fields" means, this would be the api call to get the user email: `/me?fields=email`

There is example code about how to do API calls in the official docs, check out the `fields` parameter specifically: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

For example, this should return the id, name and email of users - as long as the `email` permission got authorized in the login process, and as long as the email is confirmed on Facebook:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                   JSONObject object,
                   GraphResponse response) {
                // Application code
            }
        });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

You should also read this whole page, it explains the fields parameter and a lot more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/

Comment: i also did this but i am getting id and name only

Comment: please help me if u can dear

Comment: do you actually get asked for the email permission in the login dialog? did you debug the response of the api call? how did you debug it? do you recognize the difference between your code and my code example, with the fields parameter?

Comment: GraphRequest request =     GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

Comment: // Application code
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data" + object.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                String uname = object.optString("name");
                                String user_email = response.getJSONObject().optString("email");
                                etName.setText(uname);
                                etEmail.setText(user_email);
                                
                            }
                        });

Comment: Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields","name,email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

Comment: what is login dialog?

Comment: and please start debugging, "it does not work" is not really something we can work with...

Comment: so debug those 2 parameters (object and response)

Comment: if you really get asked for the email permission in the login process, and there is still no email...make sure you even login in facebook with an email. it does not really have to be there, people can also login with a phone number, for example.

Comment: "the dialog where you authorize your app"  

please guide me for this authorization?

Comment: thank dear 

The error is my email is not registered with facebook

Comment: ok, then make sure the email is confirmed, and you actually use an email to login, not a phone number.

Comment: yup dear,  i confirmed email and  now me getting email

Comment: can you help in a other thing ? please

Comment: this question is solved, please create a separate thread for another problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is my email is not registered with facebook

and
if you really get asked for the email permission in the login process, and there is still no email...make sure you even login in facebook with an email. it does not really have to be there, people can also login with a phone number, for example.